# 4x4x4 led cube using mm5451 chips .. need a suggestion on a Mofet or equivalent

Tags: arduino, led

My son and I are building a 4x4x4 cube. We have been planning to use a pair of mm5451 source drain chips to select the columns and were thinking to use mosfets to select and power the tier .. thus lighting the desired LED.

Since the 5451 acts as a current drain .. I am searching for a P channel MOSFET to energize the tier by using an output of the 5451 to bias the MOFET on ( it being connected to a external power supply to manage the current draw).

Is this the best approach?

Assuming yes, what would your suggestion be for a good P-chn Mosfet? ( most that I have found that will handle the external voltage/current, require more than a digital 0-5v system can put on the gate).

Thanks in advance for your help..

Answer (score 1):

You apparently have the low drive for columns figured out, and are asking about the high side drive for the rows.  I don't know what a MM5451 is, but it apparently provides some kind of open drain/collector output.

Why do you think you need to control the row drivers from this MM5451 thing?  Why not control them directly from the microcontroller producing the mux signals?  In that case, PNP transistors might be easier since it's hard to find good P channel FETs that don't need much gate drive voltage.  If you can find something equivalent to a "logic level" FET in P channel, then you can drive its gate directly from the micro.  However, it only takes a single resistor to do it with a PNP transistor, and those are definitely easily available and cheap.

How much current does this high side switch need to handle?

### Added:

Now that Russell has provided a link to the datasheet (now why couldn't you do that yourself in the first place?), it is clear this is not just a low side driver chip but also a serial to parallel converter which allows for a few control lines to drive lots of output lines.

Given that, it does make sense to also drive the rows from such a device.  Fortunately that is easy.  All it takes would be a P FET and a single resistor or a PNP bipolar transistor and two resistors.  The FET solution is one less part but the bipolar solution will be considerably cheaper.  Russell has already given you pointers to some suitable FETs.  Just about any jellybean PNP will be suitable.  I generally use MMBT4403 for such jellybean applications, but many other will do too.  Look up prices and you will see these are about a order of magnitude less than what Russell showed for the FETs.

To use a PNP for this, tie the emitter to the positive supply and the collector drives the LED anodes just like the drain of a P FET would.  Put a resistor between the base and the MM5451 output.  Size the resistor for about 1-2 mA base current.  Then add a second resistor between the base and the emitter (base and positive supply).  The purpose of this resistor is to make sure the transistor is off when the MM5451 is not driving.  Without this resistor, the base would float and the transistor could come on a little if it picked up sufficient noise.  10 kΩ is a reasonable value for this resistor.  It is high enough to only rob about 75 µA from the base current, but low enough to keep the transistor solidly off when the MM5451 output is not driving low.  This PNP drive would be my first choice unless board space is a critical issue.

Comment: The MM5451 thingy [here](http://www.micrel.com/_PDF/mm5450.pdf) is a 34 LED driver with the advantage of being easily driven with 3 lines (data, clock, reset), or, with not much effort, 1 line plus some timing & gating. It's Ye Olde steam driven but in DIP40 and PLCC44 and as a means of driving 35 or so on / off LEDs there are few easier ways. For exra points you can load it reapeatedly so it PWMs its outputs to give brightness control. Not something the makers intended.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have introduced the MM5451 to this forum a grand Olde IC still.I spent many  a happy hour playing wit it many years ago. 3 line control is intended but a few delays allows one line or pin control if wanted with good reliability.

---

**P Channel MOSFTS:**  This marvellous device [NTJS3151P](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/NTJS3151P-D.PDF)  at 44 c/1 and 12c/1000 at Digikey is rated at -12V, 3.3A, Rdson = 133 mohm at -1.8V on gate. 
Realistic gate voltage of -2V sees 0.1V drop at 1A. "Nice small" SC88 pkg to help educate you :-) :-(.

Strangely in an SOIC8 at 24 cents/1 !!! you get [STS5P20V ...](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00003660.pdf) 25V, 5A, 65 milliohm. Not so good on Vgs_th but still OK enough at 1A at 2V on gate. Datasheet says obsolete which may account for spiffing price.

You could "probably" use either  of these on high side with gates driven by MM5451. NTJS3151P has an internal 3k3 gate resistor plus series opposed  zener diodes.